# digital ocean manage sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, digital-ocean, sidekiq

I followed [Properly setting up Redis and Sidekiq in production on Ubuntu 16.04](https://thomasroest.com/2017/03/04/properly-setting-up-redis-and-sidekiq-in-production-ubuntu-16-04.html) to manage sidekiq worker

I created a file like

```
touch /lib/systemd/system/sidekiq.service
```

and added following content

```
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/ezlarm-server/current

ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec "sidekiq -e production"
User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002

Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now when I run

```
systemctl {start,stop,status,restart} sidekiq
```

it gives following errors

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its too late but have you tried `sudo systemctl {start,stop,status,restart} sidekiq`

Faced the same issue but running the command with `sudo` worked like a charm. Thanks.